# execute cfw:command means?

Tags: calendar

I've installed calfw to have a better calendar view in org mode

https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw

Following instructions I arrived to:

```
the command `cfw:open-calendar-buffer', switch to the calendar buffer.
```

My question is very basic/newbie: how to do such cfw:command thing?

Answer (score 1):

'command' in this context means a function you can call, either interactively:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`cfw:open-calendar-buffer`

or by setting up your own keybinding for it. A global binding can be done by putting something like this in your .emacs file:

`(global-set-key "\C-co" 'cfw:open-calendar-buffer)`

Comment: I've tried such thing but to no avail. M-x cfw:open-calendar-buffer Not found

Comment: That means that calfw hasn't been loaded. Did you restart emacs after adding `(require 'calfw)` to your .emacs?

Comment: yes. but no success so far. Now autocomplete shows:  cfw:open-org-calendar instead of cfw:open-calendar-buffer as options. Executed the former "no such file or directory calfw"